# What's wrong with this simple PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, dreamweaver

I've just tried to start using PDO to handle database access in PHP.

I tried the following code:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$kdbhost;dbname=$kdbname",$kdbuser,$kdbpw);
$sth = $dbh->("INSERT INTO enquiries (name, email, message) VALUES(:name, :email, :message);");
```

And dreamweaver gives me a syntax error on the second line, and I can't figure out for the life of me why?

Note I followed [this nettuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) which gave an example without the method name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO enquiries (name, email, message) VALUES(:name, :email, :message);");
```

`$dbh->(` is a syntax error because you're not calling a method of the `$dbh` object. In this case, you want to use `prepare()` to prepare the query, so you end up with:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare( ... );
```

Comment: I thought that having no method name sounded weird? - but how come this syntax is used [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) - specifically in the named placeholders section??

Comment: its clearly mistake in tutorial, you could email author to correct this. No method name is syntax error in php, it cannot be hacked to work.

Comment: @sakfa that's what I thought! - strange thing is they do it multiple times and nettuts is usually pretty good

Comment: @AlexCoplan You often get what you pay for with free internet tutorials. It's unfortunate. Stack Overflow, on the other hand, is about as reputable/correct as it gets on the Internet because everything is peer-reviewed. I haven't encountered another group of professionals as unforgiving to an incorrect or incomplete answer as programmers :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a method in your call:

```
$sth = $dbh->yourMethod("INS...
```

Replace yourMethod with prepare (if that's the method you need) or any other method provided from the PDO instance.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the prepare function name

`$sth = $dbh->`**prepare**`("INSERT INTO enquiries (name, email, message) VALUES(:name, :email, :message);");`